# My triangle printed out twice. How to solve it?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

[It printing out * and = twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLWww.png)

I'm making a sequence triangle (again), now with odd numbers only and multiplying.
It appear to be printing * and = twice.

The result should be like this:
1 = 1

1 * 3=3

1* 3* 5=15

etc

```
package javaapplication4;

public class NewClass6 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      int sum = 1;
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (j % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.print(j);
          sum *= j;
        }
        if (j == i)
          System.out.print("=");
        else if (j % 2 != 0)
          System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _i++ -> i+=2_ and _j++ -> j+=2_ since in both case when i=3 and i =4 you are printing almost same think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you have looped `i` from `1 ~ 9` and `j` from `1~i` by creasing only one per step.

It is needed to loop only odd numbers so increase 2 per step.
So `for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i +=2) {`

```
package javaapplication4;

public class NewClass6 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i+=2) {
      int sum = 1;
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j+=2) {
        if (j % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.print(j);
          sum *= j;
        }
        if (j == i)
          System.out.print("=");
        else if (j % 2 != 0)
          System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can suggest _j+=2_ also rather than skipping using if which looks smarter.

Answer (score 3):

Be simple!

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1, mul = i; i <= 9; i += 2) {
    if (buf.length() > 0)
        buf.append('*');

    buf.append(i);
    mul *= i;

    System.out.format("%s=%d\n", buf, mul);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1=1
1*3=3
1*3*5=15
1*3*5*7=105
1*3*5*7*9=945
```

Answer (score 2):

You're considering odd numbers in internal loop but you're not doing so in outer loop, either skip even numbers by changing `i++` to `i += 2` or add another `if` block for checking if `i` is not even:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) { // Skipping outer loop's even numbers
        int sum = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
            if(j % 2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.print(j);
                sum *= j; 
                if (j == i) 
                    System.out.print("=");
                else if (j % 2 != 0)
                    System.out.print("*");    
            }

        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Or skip even elements by `+= 2` rather than `++`(I would suggest using this)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i += 2) {
    int sum = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j += 2) {
        System.out.print(j);
        sum *= j; 
        if (j == i) 
            System.out.print("=");
        else if (j % 2 != 0)
            System.out.print("*");    
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```